# Why does ItemsControl is not updated?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, observablecollection

The code creates polygons using `Path`. Every time a user doubleclicks it closes the polygon and adds another `Path` object for the second polygon and so on. I'm using `PointsToPathConverter` to convert `Point`s to a collection that `Path` wants.

The points are added to `Areas` collection, but for some reason `OnPropertyChanged("Areas");` doesn't updated the `ItemsControl`. What can be the reason?

**XAML**

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Areas}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Path Data="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=PointsToPathConverter}}" Stroke="Black" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ICommand _addPointCommand;
    public ICommand AddPointCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_addPointCommand == null)
            {
                _addPointCommand = new RelayCommand<MouseButtonEventArgs>(AddPoint);
            }

            return _addPointCommand;
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<List<Point>> _areas { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<List<Point>> Areas
    {
        get
        {
            if (_areas == null)
            {
                _areas = new ObservableCollection<List<Point>>();
            }
            return _areas;
        }
    }

    public VM()
    {
        Areas = new ObservableCollection<List<Point>>();
        Areas.Add(new List<Point>());
    }

    private void AddPoint(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var curPoints = Areas[Areas.Count - 1];
        curPoints.Add(e.GetPosition((IInputElement)e.Source));

        if (e.ClickCount == 2 && curMaskPoints.Count > 0)
        {
            curMaskPoints.Add(curMaskPoints[0]);
            Areas.Add(new List<Point>());
        }

        OnPropertyChanged("Areas");
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

}

public class PointsToPathConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        #region IValueConverter Members

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var points = (value as List<Point>);
            if (points.Count > 0)
            {
                Point start = points[0];
                List<LineSegment> segments = new List<LineSegment>();
                for (int i = 1; i < points.Count; i++)
                {
                    segments.Add(new LineSegment(points[i], true));
                }
                PathFigure figure = new PathFigure(start, segments, false); //true if closed
                PathGeometry geometry = new PathGeometry();
                geometry.Figures.Add(figure);
                return geometry;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

b

Comment: `OnPropertyChanged("Areas");` is pointless, because `Areas` is an `ObservableCollection`. When you add an item to it, it will notify the `ItemsControl` right then.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, `Areas` is a collection of collection of points. When I add a new point to `Areas[X]` I want it to be reflected in UI, so I need to refresh the whole `Areas`.

Comment: **`OnPropertyChanged("Areas");` is pointless, because `Areas` is an `ObservableCollection`. When you add an item to it, it will notify the `ItemsControl` right then.** You are never, not ever, changing the value of `Areas`. Not at all, ever. It always returns the same object, every time.

Comment: You might want to notify when Areas property have changed, but here the value of Areas will never change. The value of Areas is the reference to the ObservableCollection instance.

Comment: @SirRufo, what do you mean? Every time I call `OnPropertyChanged("Areas");` should cause ItemsControl` to updated itself since `Areas` is bound to it. Even if `Areas` wasn't ObservableCollection, `OnPropertyChanged("Areas");` should still cause the `ItemsControl` to update itself.

Comment: The paint method isn't being called to refresh the control.  Try setting the ItemSource to null and then to actual data which will automatically call the paint method.

Comment: @jdweng This is WPF. `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` is bound to an `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: PropertyChanged event will only notify. Not more not less. The bound control decides how it will handle that notification, and some will compare the old value with the new one and if there is no change, they will do nothing at all.

Comment: @SirRufo, what do you mean? There is a change! I add a new point every time a user clicks here ' var curPoints = Areas[Areas.Count - 1];
        curPoints.Add(e.GetPosition((IInputElement)e.Source));'

Comment: @EdPlunkett, and then when a user clicks it addes a point to the collection  `var curPoints = Areas[Areas.Count - 1];
        curPoints.Add(e.GetPosition((IInputElement)e.Source));`. Then I raise property event changed to refresh the whole `ItemsControl`.

Comment: @theateist Ohhh, OK I getcha. Hmmm. Can you add whatever code calls the command? I'm heading home now but I'll be back.

Comment: If some friends enter your car will that change your car, or is that car now containing two more persons and will be the same? Thats what happening to the collection when adding items.

Comment: @SirRufo, I don't understand what you're saying! When I raise explicitely property changed it should update the whole `ItemsControl`.

Comment: No, it depends on the control to handle the notification

Comment: @SirRufo, If I'll change `ObservableCollection<List<Point>>` to `List<Point>` and then will explicitely call 'RaisePropertyChanged` it will update `ItemsControl`. I've done this many times.. For some reason it doesn't work with `List<List<Point>>`.

Comment: @theateist "For some reason"?! Those are totally different types! Put a breakpoint in your converter's `Convert`  method and step through it once or twice to see what's happening in the version that works and in the version that doesn't.

Comment: You need something like an ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<ObservablePoint>>

Comment: @SirRufo He just might. Good heavens. Well, he can replace a point in the inner ObservableCollection, no need for the point to be observable. INotifyCollectionChanged can work with that.

Comment: You guys just didn't help at all! All just guesses. You even didn't read the code! I tried everything and I couldn't do it. That's why I posted it here. If you cannot help don't answer. If you can help, post a very short example of `ObservableCollection<List<Point>>` that when you add something to it the `ItemsControl` gets updated.

Comment: Sorry, we cant. We could do it with ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<Point>> ... but you can too. Just change List<Point> to ObservableCollection<Point>

Comment: @EdPlunkett, I'm using `GalaSoft.MvvmLight` library that handles the `EventToCommand`. But, it's not the problem. I'm pretty sure, since if I don't use `ItemsControl` but single `Path` and bind it to `Areas2` which is `List<Point>` and then explicitely call 'OnPropertyChanged(Areas2)` it works as expected. But, it doesn't work when I use collection of collection

Comment: @theateist Did you change the converter to use ObservableCollection too? Your opinion about where the problem is isn't worth much, clearly. I want to reproduce the problem. Tell me how you add points. How do you add points? Mouse down?

Comment: @theateist I just got the cause of your problem. Binding will happen when the bound value changed. The Path is bound to a list instance (an item of the areas collection) with a value converter, but the list instance will never change only the content of the list. No change, no notify, no update. Now knowing the cause we can look for a solution

Comment: The comments here were going off the rails into personal attacks, so I cleaned them up. Please try to be civil and polite, everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the fix. Making the nested collection observable doesn't help. You need to replace the nested collection with a new collection, of either type -- containing the same set of points. Doesn't matter which type of collection you use. Just needs to be a different collection object *instance*.

```
private void AddPoint(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var curPoints = Areas[Areas.Count - 1];
    curPoints.Add(e.GetPosition((IInputElement)e.Source));

    //  ** fix ** 
    Areas[Areas.Count - 1] = new List<Point>(curPoints);
    //  ** end fix ** 

    if (e.ClickCount == 2 && curMaskPoints.Count > 0)
    {
        curMaskPoints.Add(curMaskPoints[0]);
        Areas.Add(new List<Point>());
    }
}
```

Sir Rufo's much more respectable fix will do the same thing for the same reason: It forces the notification to happen, just by a different mechanism.

Comment: ... and with less mem stress (copying of the Point structs) :o)

Comment: @SirRufo Bah. Nobody clicks that much :)

Comment: @EdPlunkett, I actually did similar to your solution. I just delete and reAdd the collection. `Masks.RemoveAt(Masks.Count - 1);
                Masks.Add(curMaskPoints);` and it works.

Comment: @theateist Same difference.

Comment: But, I don't understand why `OnPropertyChanged("Areas");` doesn't force the `ItemsControl` to update?

Comment: @theateist Google it.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of your problem is here

```xml
<Path Data="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=PointsToPathConverter}}" Stroke="Black" />
```

For updating of the `Path.Data` there has to be a notification for that.

Modify your code to

```
public class ObservableArea : GalaSoft.MvvmLight.ObservableObject
{
    public ObservableArea()
    {
        Points = new ObservableCollection<Point>();
        Points.CollectionChanged += ( s, e ) => RaisePropertyChanged( nameof( Points ) );
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Point> Points { get; }
}

public class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ICommand _addPointCommand;
    public ICommand AddPointCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_addPointCommand == null)
            {
                _addPointCommand = new RelayCommand<MouseButtonEventArgs>(AddPoint);
            }

            return _addPointCommand;
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<ObservableArea> _areas { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ObservableArea> Areas
    {
        get
        {
            if (_areas == null)
            {
                _areas = new ObservableCollection<ObservableArea>();
            }
            return _areas;
        }
    }

    public VM()
    {
        Areas = new ObservableCollection<ObservableArea>();
        Areas.Add(new ObservableArea());
    }

    private void AddPoint(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var curPoints = Areas[Areas.Count - 1];
        curPoints.Points.Add(e.GetPosition((IInputElement)e.Source));

        if (e.ClickCount == 2 && curMaskPoints.Count > 0)
        {
            curMaskPoints.Add(curMaskPoints[0]);
            Areas.Add(new ObservableArea());
        }
        // useless and can be removed
        // OnPropertyChanged("Areas");
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

}
```

and XAML to

```xml
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Areas}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Path Data="{Binding Path=Points, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=PointsToPathConverter}}" Stroke="Black" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

## AddOn

Just as a proove, why raising the `PropertyChanged` event is useless on a property which value has not changed:

`Areas` is bound to the `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` property which is a `DependencyProperty` ([have a look at the Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/PresentationFramework/R/db985380eb10dd22.html)) and a change of the control presentation will only happen on a real change of the value, because the DP logic itself will compare the new and old value and if not equal then it will call the PropertyChangedCallback (see `ItemsControl.OnItemsSourceChanged` in Reference Source).

Whenever a `PropertyChanged` event is raised the binding will assign the values, but if the values are the same as the old values there will be no more action.

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var foo = new Foo();

        Console.WriteLine( "Set foo.Bar to 1" );
        foo.Bar = 1;
        Console.WriteLine( "Set foo.Bar to 1 (assigning the same value)" );
        foo.Bar = 1;
        Console.WriteLine( "Set foo.Bar to 2" );
        foo.Bar = 2;
    }
}

public class Foo : DependencyObject
{
    public int Bar
    {
        get { return (int) GetValue( BarProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( BarProperty, value ); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BarProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Bar",
            typeof( int ),
            typeof( Foo ),
            new PropertyMetadata(
                defaultValue: 0,
                propertyChangedCallback: new PropertyChangedCallback( OnBarChanged ) ) );

    private static void OnBarChanged( DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "OnBarChanged: Property has changed from '{0}' to '{1}'", e.OldValue, e.NewValue );
    }
}
```

[Run it live on .netfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nXozu8)

Comment: I do have notification for the change. It's in `OnPropertyChanged("Areas");`.

Comment: @theateist That notification is, as I told you, a waste of time. It has no effect. We both fixed your problem. We both removed that pointless notification in doing so.

Comment: Well, try it and you will see your notification of Areas is useless. I just comment it out here